# Is org.apache.tinkerpop (tinkergraph-gremlin) 3.5.2 version compatible with JDK 17

Tags: maven, gremlin, tinkerpop, java-17

The project currently uses tinkergraph-gremlin verson 3.5.2 of org.apache.tinkerpop with JAVA 11. The upgrade is required from Java 11 to Java 17 and wanted to know if org.apache.tinkerpop 3.5.2 version will be compatible with Java 17 or not. Can someone please let me know if there will be any issues to use org.apache.tinkerpop 3.5.2 version with java 17 or how we can check that?

I checked in Java 17 and Apache documentations to look for answers but couldn't find specific one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JIRA describes one of the main reasons why TinkerPop is currently blocked on moving to Java 17: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2633

Comment: note some additional discussion here: https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/kAOkWi-oSi0 where folks have found it possible to make it work